# CSS reset: Why do headings ignore * { margin: 0; }?

Tags: css, reset, typography

Normalize is cool. But I seriously hate margins/padding/box-sizing.

When I set `* { margin: 0; }` it seems to appropriately reset every element except heading (h1, h2, etc..) elements.

What is going on? How can I reset these elements?

Comment: [It should work](https://jsfiddle.net/kcLbk7cf/). Maybe your overriding those styles later? Can you post your full markup.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element?

Comment: @Vucko you're right! I'm an idiot. https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css#L146-L149

I'm really getting sick of Normalize's margin crap. They apply margins to `<figure>` as well even though none of the other html5 elements get margins... Make your comment an answer and I'll accept seeing as how the other answers completely miss the point. Do people even read these questions before answering?

Answer (score 0):

**Browsers have different default stylesheets.**

That's why developers often use some type of css reset like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

If you want to eliminate unwanted margins in all browsers, try adding this (or normalize.css):

```
*, html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
```

There are lots of other options for css resets as well - [Eric Meyers](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) came up with a good one.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a complete CSS reset like this bad boy here - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
You will have to manually style everything though, including your heading and lists